# why is this code giving me the output "b" instead of "c"

Tags: python, if-statement

> what will be the output of this code and why

```
options = "year2"
options1 = "semester1"
if (options == "year1") and (options1 == "semester1"):
    print("a")
elif (options == "year1" or "year3" or "year4") and (options1 == "semester2" or "semester3"):
    print("b")
elif (options == "year2" or "year3" or "year4") and (options1 == "semester1"):
    print("c")
else:
    print("d")
```

Comment: Hint: The value `"year3"` by itself is considered [truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983695/328193), as is any other string.  As a result, the second condition (the first `elif`) will *always* be true.

Comment: `(options == "year1" or "year3" or "year4")` will execute without error, but will always return `TRUE`. Instead perhaps `(options == "year1" or options == "year3" or options == "year4")` is what was meant? Note that `OR` and `AND` evaluate individual conditions, not a condition and a bunch of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like

```
options in ("year1", "year2", ...)
```

The Misunderstanding here is, that you connect  with or

<options == "year1"> or <"year3"> ...

<options == "year1"> might or migth not be true
<"year3"> is equivalent to bool("year3") which will be always true